# ImageJ keeps running / Some Thread is not stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, image, bufferedimage, imagej

I try to use the ImageJ Library to process images. My problem is, that some thread is never stopped. Eclipse always shows me an active thread running. This happens if I pass a value > 0 to the function below. It seems ImageJ opens a thread internaly whenever it has something to process (eg. blurGaussian(0.1).

How can I stop this thread?

My Code:

```
public static BufferedImage preProcessBufferedImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage, double sigma) throws IOException {
    ImagePlus imagePlus = new ImagePlus("", bufferedImage);
    imagePlus.getProcessor().blurGaussian(sigma);
    return imagePlus.getBufferedImage();
}
```

Library used:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.imagej/ij/1.53h

Answer (score 0):

How about ImagePlus.close() ? It seems as this clas has a closing method. Use it.

```
public static BufferedImage preProcessBufferedImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage, double sigma) throws IOException {
    ImagePlus imagePlus = new ImagePlus("", bufferedImage);
    BufferedImage blurredImage = imagePlus.getProcessor().blurGaussian(sigma).getBufferedImage();
    imagePLus.close();
    return blurredImage;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this. Thread still running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only solution I found is to use `ij.Prefs.setThreads(1);` before the call to the blurGaussian method.